# Loading data to arcgis Online from QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap

I have uploaded some data to arcgis online to create a web map, even converted to WGS84 from BNG before zipping, I am using QGIS to create my maps, I do have a desktop licence for ArcGIS but trying to use QGIS to not rely on ArcGIS desktop. You can see after loading to arcgis Online the features have shifted to the left and south.

See pictures below.

[image: QGIS Screenshot]

[image: Arcgis Online Screenshot of same data]

Comment: Is it possible your data was digitized from different aerial imagery than is shown on the second image?

Comment: The aerial imagery is from ESRI basemap, I created my features using OS features which in this case is the fence north of feature, I only view satellite imagery for seeing where trees were

Comment: By "OS features" do you mean Open Street Map/Ordnance Survey?something else?  Have you overlaid your features on the OSM basemap in ArcGIS Online?

Comment: I mean ordnance Survey, I have tested with OS basemaps such as OS Carto but does zoom in far and my features are more detailed, I think they are roughly in the same place
I have projected another file in ArcGIS Pro and uploaded it and it has come through in exactly the right place, also when doing this there are are cpg, sbn, sbx file extensions with the shapefile whereas they are not with QGIS don't know if makes difference

Comment: Is your data in WGS84 datum?  If not it could be a projection issue and you could try reprojecting it to WGS84 and see if it lines up better after on AGOL.

Comment: Did you convert the projection using QGIS? ESRI uses a PRJ file for projection data, while QGIS uses a PRJ and a QPJ file. QGIS can read the ESRI format, but ESRI can't read the QGIS format. See this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55545/qpj-files-on-esri-software

Comment: I converted using QGIS from OSGB 36 to WGS84 in qgis but didn’t align in AGOL, when did in arcgis pro it aligned using project tool, when zipping files from QGIS I tried including all and everything but qpj neither made much difference, will try things tonight